# SSRS Function with Regex Match

Tags: regex, ssrs-2008-r2

In a report I'm trying to filter rows where a values does not match the pattern of ten digits and zero or more hyphens.

As I need the data in other tables, I thought the best way is to use the tablix filter. In the expression match the field with a regex: `^([\d]{10})-*$` and set it to equal false.

I'm trying this expression:

```
=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Fields!Number.Value, "^([\d]{10})-*$")
```

However, it returns the error that the filter failed to evaluate. 
Any ideas how to fix it?

Alternatively I can take the left 10 characters and test if they are an integer, but then I can't think of a simple clean way for testing for the hyphens, and prefer the regex.

Comment: Try `"^([0-9]{10})-*$"`

Comment: I did and it worked. Surprisingly it also worked when I changed the `[0-9]` back to `[\d]`. I did a restart in between, perhaps it was a strange cache issue which i seem to experience more often. Thanks!

Comment: @G684 you can delete the .data file that is created in the same folder as your .rdl file to clear the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression works fine after a reboot:

`=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Fields!Number.Value, "^([\d]{10})-*$")`